# Remove JSONP for parsing in HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Google's definition URL which returns a response stream containing JSONP data (see below).

```
GET http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=epitome
```

The response looks like this:

```
a({"query": "epitome", ...}, 200, null)
```

Before parsing the JSON, I have to strip the callback parameters; that means removing everything before the first `{` and everything after the last `}`.

I have  regular expression to strip the callback parameters but am having problems using it with an HTTParty request.

Regular Expression to strip padding

```
^\w+\(|[^}]+$
```

I've tried using the following, but am getting errors.

```
base_url = "http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q="
word = "epitome"

request = HTTParty.get("#{base_url}#{word}").gsub(/^\w+\(|[^}]+$/)
```

HTTParty automatically tries to parse the data ignoring the `gsub!` method; so I'm not sure how to add the regexp to strip the callback parameters before HTTParty tries to parse the returned data.

Any tips on this?

Comment: Please don't put a link to the data you're trying to parse. WHEN that link breaks it will be very difficult for others to get anything useful from your question. Instead, supply a minimal example of the JSONP *in your question*. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a custom parser. In this example, I use a substring to strip off the padding, but you could use a regex if you prefer:

```
require 'httparty'

class JsonpParser < HTTParty::Parser
  SupportedFormats = {"text/javascript" => :jsonp}

  def jsonp
    JSON.load(body[2..-11], nil)
  end

end

class Dictionary
  include HTTParty

  parser JsonpParser

  def self.define(word)
    get "http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=#{word}"
  end

end

Dictionary.define 'epitome'
```

Answer (score 5):

This is really easy to do, without anything but regular Ruby and the [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html) and [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) classes that come with it. Consider this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

URL = 'http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=epitome'
jsonp = open(URL).read
```

At this point, `jsonp` contains the response from Google's API. The portion you want is wrapped in curly-braces `{...}`.

Regular expressions are greedy and will gobble up everything they can. Often that's a problem, but in this case it's good. A simple pattern of `/{.+}/` will find everything from the first `{` to the last `}`, which is the JSON payload, and, at that point, you're ready to parse:

```
payload = jsonp[/{.+}/]
# => "{\"query\":\"epitome\",\"sourceLanguage\":\"en\",\"targetLanguage\":\"en\",\"primaries\":[{\"type\":\"headword\",\"terms\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"e·pit·o·me\",\"language\":\"en\",\"labels\":[{\"text\":\"Noun\",\"title\":\"Part-of-speech\"}]},{\"type\":\"phonetic\",\"text\":\"/iˈpitəmē/\",\"language\":\"und\"},{\"type\":\"sound\",\"text\":\"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/epitome.mp3\",\"language\":\"und\"}],\"entries\":[{\"type\":\"related\",\"terms\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"epitomes\",\"language\":\"und\",\"labels\":[{\"text\":\"plural\"}]}]},{\"type\":\"meaning\",\"terms\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"A person or thing that is a perfect example of a particular quality or type\",\"language\":\"en\"}],\"entries\":[{\"type\":\"example\",\"terms\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"she looked the \\x3cem\\x3eepitome\\x3c/em\\x3e of elegance and good taste\",\"language\":\"en\"}]}]},{\"type\":\"meaning\",\"terms\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"A summary of a written work; an abstract\",\"language\":\"en\"}]},{\"type\":\"meaning\",\"terms\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"A thing representing something else in miniature\",\"language\":\"en\"}]}]}]}"
```

Parse that:

```
data = JSON.parse(payload)
# => {"query"=>"epitome",
#     "sourceLanguage"=>"en",
#     "targetLanguage"=>"en",
#     "primaries"=>
#      [{"type"=>"headword",
#        "terms"=>
#         [{"type"=>"text",
#           "text"=>"e·pit·o·me",
#           "language"=>"en",
#           "labels"=>[{"text"=>"Noun", "title"=>"Part-of-speech"}]},
#          {"type"=>"phonetic", "text"=>"/iˈpitəmē/", "language"=>"und"},
#          {"type"=>"sound",
#           "text"=>
#            "http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/epitome.mp3",
#           "language"=>"und"}],
#        "entries"=>
#         [{"type"=>"related",
#           "terms"=>
#            [{"type"=>"text",
#              "text"=>"epitomes",
#              "language"=>"und",
#              "labels"=>[{"text"=>"plural"}]}]},
#          {"type"=>"meaning",
#           "terms"=>
#            [{"type"=>"text",
#              "text"=>
#               "A person or thing that is a perfect example of a particular quality or type",
#              "language"=>"en"}],
#           "entries"=>
#            [{"type"=>"example",
#              "terms"=>
#               [{"type"=>"text",
#                 "text"=>
#                  "she looked the x3cemx3eepitomex3c/emx3e of elegance and good taste",
#                 "language"=>"en"}]}]},
#          {"type"=>"meaning",
#           "terms"=>
#            [{"type"=>"text",
#              "text"=>"A summary of a written work; an abstract",
#              "language"=>"en"}]},
#          {"type"=>"meaning",
#           "terms"=>
#            [{"type"=>"text",
#              "text"=>"A thing representing something else in miniature",
#              "language"=>"en"}]}]}]}
```

Now you've got a good ol' Ruby hash you can access normally:

```
data['query'] # => "epitome"
```

To summarize:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

URL = 'http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=epitome'

data = JSON.parse(open(URL).read[/{.+}/])

data['query'] # => "epitome"
data['primaries'].size # => 1
```

And, it'll work with regular JSON results too, so you don't have to do anything special to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

Update httparty to latest version as this was fixed [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/commit/b7d4e21c5b8b65ecaf5743348971bc7324e1a090). Parsing javascript response as JSON was disabled which means that `HTTParty.get` will return a string and you can do the substitution and parsing yourself.

It will only work if the response has correct content type (the Google service in your example does).